# fix navbar dropdown bad positioning and only working on one page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So I've been making a website for me and my friends to use at school due to them blocking eveything so I made my own chat system etc.. I'm looking for some help to fix my navbar dropdown, currently doesn't work at all but there is tags in the php for it is someone could please see if there is a fix that would be great!
HOPEFULLY THE ANSWERS ON THIS POST WILL BE USEFUL FOR OTHER PEOPLE LOOKING FOR THE SAME FUNCTIONS!

header.php

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat";

/* ===========================================
                    Titles
============================================ */
.title, div.title, .title-left {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 40px 0 0 0;
  color: #6C6C6C;
  margin: 0; }

div.title, div.title-left {
  padding: 20px 0; }

.title-left {
  text-align: left; }


/* ===========================================
                Buttons
============================================ */
.button, .button-primary {
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 0; }

.button-primary {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -webkit-transition: 700ms background ease-in-out;
  transition: 700ms background ease-in-out;
  background: #1DB2E3;
  color: #FFFFFF; }
  .button-primary:hover {
    background: #333E4F; }

/* ===========================================
            Main Navigation
============================================ */
#main-navigation {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  min-height: 90px;
  z-index: 999; 
  }
  #main-navigation .navigation-left {
    padding: 37px 0;
    float: left; }
    #main-navigation .navigation-left a.logo {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #FFFFFF; }
      #main-navigation .navigation-left a.logo img {
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: 60px; }
  #main-navigation .hamburger-menu {
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    right: -70%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; }
  #main-navigation .bar,
  #main-navigation .bar:after,
  #main-navigation .bar:before {
    height: 2px;
    width: 30px; }
  #main-navigation .bar {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px);
    transform: translateY(9px);
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0ms 300ms;
    transition: all 0ms 300ms;
    position: relative; }
    #main-navigation .bar.animate {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
  #main-navigation .bar:before {
    -webkit-transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    background: white;
    bottom: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0; }
  #main-navigation .bar:after {
    -webkit-transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    content: "";
    left: 0; }
  #main-navigation .bar.animate:before {
    -webkit-transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom: 0; }
  #main-navigation .bar.animate:after {
    -webkit-transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), -webkit-transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0; }
  #main-navigation .navigation-right {
    padding: 37px 0;
    display: none;
    float: right; }
    #main-navigation .navigation-right .item {
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-right: 15px;
      color: #FFFFFF; }
  @media (min-width: 480px) {
    #main-navigation .navigation-right {
      display: block; }
    #main-navigation .hamburger-menu {
      display: none; } }

.navigation-right.active {
  display: block !important;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 95px;
  height: 352px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; }
  .navigation-right.active a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 0;
    display: block; }
  .navigation-right.active .button-primary {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%; }

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  margin-right: 60px;}

.dropdown.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: block !important; }
  .dropdown.active a {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #AAAAAA;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF; }
    .dropdown.active a:last-child {
      border: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 480px) {
    .dropdown.active {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 15px 20px;
      margin-top: 34px;
      margin-left: 16em;
      } }

/* OTHER */

body {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}


html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15;
  /* 2 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 3 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}  
  
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <title>MopedBoyz</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/mopedIcon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>

            <div id="main-navigation" class="animated bounceInDown">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="navigation-left">
                    <a href="index.php" class="logo bold">MopedBoyz</a>
                </div>

                <div class="hamburger-menu">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation-right">
                    <a href="index.php" class="item">Links</a>
                    <a href="chat.php" class="item">Chat</a>
                    <a href="login.php" class="item">Login</a>
                    <a href="register.php" class="item">Register</a>
                    <a href="usercp.php" class="item">Settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="item hosting-dropdown">Account
                     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                            <a href="register.php">Register</a>
                            <a href="usercp.php">Settings</a>
                            <a href="sys/logout.php">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    <a href="sys/logout.php" class="button-primary">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Include your CSS file in the question, nobody will read 3000 Lines but if you can provide a [mcve] that would be great!

Comment: problem is, with it being 3000 lines a 'minimal reproducible example' is hard to produce, i can do my best bust cannot guarentee that it wil fully work, the only thing i can suggest is creating a quick index.php adding the header tag in using the header.php i provided and then compltely copying all that css <link rel> it to the php file and just go through the css using ctrl+f and find the dropdown and the navigation area and try and diagnose it there, I've tried doing so myself be being uneducated i cannot fix it.

Comment: Hey @MrWilliamJM you can copy in only the necessary code used in your HTML. This are usually the ```id``` and ```class``` tags. Hence check the css for ```main-navigation animated bounceInDown inner, etc.```. This will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: @s1x There, added a "basic" rundown of the css needed for the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If was pretty difficult to read your 3000 lines css code, but i made you a working example. You can find it on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfq1Lyzt/2/).

I think you should structure the 'dropdown' container as below:

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="usercp.php">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="sys/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
 </ul>
```

'li' tags should be placed inside 'ul' as above.

The whole 'dropdown' container should be placed inside the 'hosting-dropdown' which opens and close the 'dropdown'. So you can adjust the 'dropdown' container position relative to the 'hosting-dropdown' button.

```
 <div id="dropdown" class="item hosting-dropdown">
      <span>Account<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="usercp.php">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="sys/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Dropdown open and close can be realised with a small jQuery function:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
  })
})
```

And the CSS:

```
.hosting-dropdown { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}  

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 55px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none; 
}

.hosting-dropdown.opened .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.main-navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#fff
}

#main-navigation .navigation-left {
  padding: 27px 0;   
}
#main-navigation .navigation-right{
  padding: 35px 0; 
}
```

If you have any question please contact me.

Comment: Still struggling to get this to work on my site dude, looks amazing on jsfiddle but adding it to the header.php and intergrating it into the main site is the problem.